# Self service client_id and client_secret on azure developer portal

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm doing some tests with Azure APIM and have already published an API on the developer portal. I have the docs, have it secured using OAuth2 with Azure AD with client_credentials flow. I can invoke this API from Postman and [from the developer portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-oauth2).

Unfortunatelly, the client_id and secret are set on the configuration and the developer cannot self service them. Is there a way to do so instead of having to add it manually to each developer?

I was looking for something like this: https://tyk.io/docs/tyk-stack/tyk-developer-portal/portal-oauth-clients/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure APIM itself doesn't act as an identity provider like tyk but instead uses Azure AD (or rather any OAuth 2.0 provider).

The configuration in the docs is primarily to get the Developer Portal Console (the one used to test APIs) to work. For the actual API calls, there is no configuration required.

The [`validate-jwt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT) policy is what takes care of preauthorization of requests.

Since you are looking for the client credentials flow alone, you could simply expose a portal that can create the required app registrations on your Azure AD using the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0) and expose the client id/secret to your users.

The current developer portal doesn't support this as of today but is something you could [contribute to](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal) if you wish.